# Can't upload files using livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I can't submit a form with file in order to proced to upload method, the file is selected when I submit it says that the file is required (empty data).
Everything works fine on mylocal Windows machine but I face the problem when using vps for production.

view :

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  
    <div>
        @if(session()->has('message'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{ session('message') }}
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
  
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Enter title" wire:model="title">
        @error('title') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName">File:</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" wire:model="file">
        @error('file') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
    </div>
  
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</form>
```

controller :

```
    use WithFileUploads;
    public $file, $title;

    
    public function submit()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'file' => 'required',
        ]);
  
        $validatedData['name'] = $this->file->store('files', 'public');
  
        // File::create($validatedData);
  
        session()->flash('message', 'File successfully Uploaded.');
    }
```

VPS folders :

[image]

I tried to change permessions, user group.... no success.

Comment: The problem is Cloudflare or any proxy.
the solution is : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
use WithFileUploads;

public $title;
public $file;

protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:50'],
        'file' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:pdf,doc,docx', 'max:5000']
    ];
}

public function submit()
{
    $this->validate();
    $data = [
        'title' => $this->title
    ];

    if (!empty($this->file)) {
        $url = $this->file->store('files', 'public');
        $data['file'] = $url;
    }

    File::create($data);

    session()->flash('message', 'File successfully Uploaded.');

}
```

Comment: Why should anyone "try this"? A good answer includes some description as to *why* this should work and *what* you changed.